# matplotlib use same color in a loop using cycler

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot where the color will change in evrey loop, not in every plot. By default, as shown in example, the color or scatter and line will be different if I dont use `color=colors[q]`. But, for that, I am using `q` as a counter.

Is there any way to use the same color using the `cycler` and avoiding the `q` and the explicit `colors` list?

```
colors = [
  '#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b',
  '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf'
]
q = 0
for i in range(int(len(line_titles) / 2)):
  plt.scatter(x[i],
              y[i],
              color=colors[q],
              label=line_titles[q],
              marker="o")
  plt.plot(x[i], y[i], color=colors[q], linestyle='--')
  q = q + 1
```

Comment: use `i` instead of `q`?

Comment: i am ready if that gives me what i asked about cyclers and colors list. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the color out of the scatter plot PathCollection object and use it in the second plot command:

```
spc = plt.scatter(x, y, ...)
plt.plot(x, y, color=spc.get_facecolor()[0], linestyle="--")
```